# Добавить столбец с родительским ID

Tags: postgresql

Есть набор данных, мне нужно определить связь родитель - ребенок.

Для этого нужно добавить столбец parent_id с id родителя, но я не пойму алгоритм, как указать нужного родителя по условию вхождения подстроки.
PostgreSQL 12.1

См.Рис

[image]

Aggregate - количество знаков в коде

Например:

- code 20 самый верхний уровень, parent_id = 0
- у code 2001 родитель 20, записываем в parent_id=1
- у code 200110 родитель 2001, записываем в parent_id=2

у code 20011010 родитель 200110, записываем в parent_id=10
и тд.

```
create temp table groups (id serial,code int,aggregate int);

insert into groups (code,aggregate) values
(20,2),
(2001,4),
(2002,4),
(2003,4),
(2004,4),
(200110,6),
(200190,6),
(200210,6),
(200290,6),
(20011010,8),
(20021090,8);
```

Comment: Вы пытаетесь изобрести крайне замысловатый велосипед, если это не является самоцелью посмотрите LTREE https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/14/ltree

Answer (score 0):

Для начала создаёте вычисляемый столбец:

```
ALTER TABLE
    ADD COLUMN code_str varchar(8) GENERATED ALWAYS AS to_char(code) STORED;
```

И сам новый столбец `parent_id` с foregin key на `id`.